# How can I register class as singleton depending on optional argument in Autofac?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac

Let me explain my question using code, so I have a class:

```
public class ComplexEntity
{
    private readonly ISomeDependency _someDependency;
    private readonly int _optionalArg;

    public ComplexEntity(ISomeDependency someDependency, int optionalArg)
    {
        _someDependency = someDependency;
        _optionalArg = optionalArg;
    }
}
```

and module:

```
public class FooModule : Module
{
    protected override void OnMap(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<ConcreteDependency>().As<ISomeDependency>().SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterType<ComplexEntity>().AsSelf();//SingleInstance fails my test below. 
    }
}
```

so my question is - how can I resolve `ComplexEntity` using optional argument (of type int - actually it doesn't matter what type is) and according to that optional argument it will return me same entity (if was already requested with) or create a new one - just take a look at the following test:

```
    int optionalArgument = 10;
    int anotherOptionalArgument = 11;

    //I expect ResolveOptional returns same references for the same optional argument, 
    //thus instance1 should be equals instance2, but not equals instance3
    var instance1 = _container.ResolveOptional<ComplexEntity>(
        new TypedParameter(optionalArgument.GetType(), optionalArgument));
    var instance2 = _container.ResolveOptional<ComplexEntity>(
        new TypedParameter(optionalArgument.GetType(), optionalArgument));

    var instance3 = _container.ResolveOptional<ComplexEntity>(
        new TypedParameter(anotherOptionalArgument.GetType(), anotherOptionalArgument));

    bool ref12Equals = object.ReferenceEquals(instance1, instance2); //should be true
    bool ref13Equals = object.ReferenceEquals(instance1, instance3); //should be false
    bool ref23Equals = object.ReferenceEquals(instance2, instance3); //should be false
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve here. It looks like you are registering test types in a test module. So why can't you make the registration according to the requirements of your test?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, Ok, I removed all test mentions.

Comment: How many differnet arguements you have? Are they known at the time you build your container?

Comment: @nemesv, usually one, but it shouldn't matter. Yes they are known. So I found out that there is no way - I have to implement cache mechanism by hand :(

Answer (score 0):

In autofac scope can either be singleton or factory (transient), not both. If you need more complex lifetime management, I belive you need to take responsibility for that and manage that yourself. If I understood you properly, you need a scope manager that either produces new instance or returns singleton. If you still want to use DI, you can put it in container, like this:

```
    private const int FactoryMode = 11;
    private const int SingletonMode = 10;

    public static void Main()
    {
        var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<ComplexTypeScope>().SingleInstance();
        containerBuilder.Register((c, p) => c.Resolve<ComplexTypeScope>().Get(p.TypedAs<int>()));

        var container = containerBuilder.Build();
        ComplexType instance1 = container.Resolve<ComplexType>(new TypedParameter(typeof(int), SingletonMode));
        ComplexType instance2 = container.Resolve<ComplexType>(new TypedParameter(typeof(int), SingletonMode));
        ComplexType instance3 = container.Resolve<ComplexType>(new TypedParameter(typeof(int), FactoryMode));

        Debug.Assert(ReferenceEquals(instance1, instance2));
        Debug.Assert(!ReferenceEquals(instance1, instance3));
    }

    class ComplexType
    {
    }

    class ComplexTypeScope
    {
        private readonly Lazy<ComplexType> complexTypeSingleTon;

        public ComplexTypeScope()
        {
            complexTypeSingleTon = new Lazy<ComplexType>(() => new ComplexType());
        }

        public ComplexType Get(int parameter)
        {
            return parameter == FactoryMode ? new ComplexType() : complexTypeSingleTon.Value;
        }
    }
```

of course with such an approach container does not manage lifetime of the components, like automatic disposal.